# How to change the dir root of docker image storage

Tags: docker

I using docker to build some images. To space drive space I decide to change the default docker images and containers storage ('/var/lib/docker') to my additional drive ('/mnt')

I change the '/lib/systemd/system/docker.service', and add

`'ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -g /mnt/data'`

The problem is when I indicate dir root like that it works like a charm, but if I want to go deeper, for example

```
'ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -g /mnt/data/subFolder/AABB'
```

When I `'systemctl daemon-reload'` and `'service docker restart'`
I got error:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-08-16 16:25:28 EDT; 46s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 4543 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -g /mnt/data/subFolder/AABB (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4543 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 16 16:25:28 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 16 16:25:28 myserver systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 16 16:25:28 myserver systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 16 16:25:28 myserver systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 16 16:25:28 myserver systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 16 16:25:28 myserver systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 16 16:25:28 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

I have check the ownership and right for them which are

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 16 16:23 data
&
drwxrwxrwx 4 root  root 49 Aug  8 10:23 AABB
```

Does anyone have idea why that happens?
Any help appreciated!

A bit update, I find after I change the root (e.g."/mnt/data")
the right of this folder is changed as well

```
drwx--x--x 12 root root 4096 Aug 16 16:40 data
```

Although it is doable to change it back, It would be great if you can give me some clue

Here is more update, the `/subFolder/` seems to be NFS share folder, that might be the reason.

So it there any way that I can use the folder as docker image and container storage?

Comment: Are you sure that you have completely stopped docker service before you are trying to reload? You can verify it using `ps aux | grep -i docker | grep -v grep`

Comment: @Ayushya Than you for responding me, and yes, I do stop it

Answer (score 0):

images are sored in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`

you can move this folder and than create symlink to it new location

```
systemctl stop docker
mv /var/lib/docker/overlay2 /raid/docker-overlay2-data
ln -s /raid/docker-overlay2-data /var/lib/docker
systemctl start docker
```